# MS Access textbox control move other controls while it is growing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have e simple report on MS Access, I have a text box with its CanGrow property set to Yes, the problem is that when it grows then other controls move down, this other controls are in the same imaginary row, I want this control to conserve their positions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a screenshot of the design view would help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Top` position of the other controls is not greater (=lower) than the the control with `CanGrow`.

Then the other controls will not move down.